# dividing two columns grouped by region in R

Tags: r, division

I'm trying to divide two columns via month by amount grouped by their region.

My dataset looks like this:

```
month   Amount  Region
10      2       APAC
20      5       EMEA
10      3       APAC
10      4       NA
4       3       NA
```

I have tried the below code however it gives me incorrect answer

```
a <- t(aggregate(data$month/data$Amount, by=list(region=data$Region), FUN=sum))
```

I get the below results:

```
       [,1]       [,2]       [,3]      
region "APAC"     "EMEA"     "NA"      
x      "8.333333" "4.000000" "3.833333"
```

The desired output is:

```
       [,1]       [,2]       [,3]      
region "APAC"     "EMEA"     "NA"      
x      "4            "4"      3"
```

However it is incorrect. Can anyone tell where am I going wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: this should be the output
APAC EMEA NA
4           4            2

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56540923/edit) your post.

Comment: for the region APAC, sum of money that is 20 divided by sum of amount which is 5 so 20/5 gives me 4,likewise for all the regions...sum(money)/sum(amount) group by region.

Comment: @zx8754  Your possible dupe tagged is reopened by somebody.

Comment: Revision history is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56540923/revisions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can first add `NA` level in `Region`, then `aggregate` by `Region` and take `sum` and finally divide the columns.

```
df$Region <- addNA(df$Region)
df1 <- aggregate(.~Region, df, sum)
df1$output <- df1$month/df1$Amount

df1
#  Region month Amount output
#1   APAC    20      5      4
#2   EMEA    20      5      4
#3   <NA>    14      7      2
```

---

Same using `dplyr` can be done as

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Region) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(month, Amount), sum) %>%
  mutate(output = month/Amount)
```

Comment: I tried this, however i get this : Error in Summary.factor(c(4L, 1L), na.rm = FALSE) : 
  ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors..I am using the dplyr library

Comment: @PoojaGangurde First change `month` and `Amount` column to numeric then. Do `df[1:2] <- lapply(df[1:2], function(x)  as.numeric(as.character(x)))` and then use any of the above solution.

Comment: I changed it too numeric...still the same error...i tried changing to numeric with this as.numeric(as.character(data$month)) as well, yet the same error...

Comment: @PoojaGangurde Can you update your post with `dput(data)` ?

Comment: sorry m fairly new to R,is this you want structure(list(Name = c("Pooja", "Nayana", "Arhant", "Maya", 
"Maya"), Surname = c("Gangurde", "Gangurde", "Gangurde", "Gangurde", 
"Gangurde"), Title = c("Ms", "Ms", "Ms", "Ms", "Ms"), Designation = c("Analyst", 
"DM", "DM", "DM", "DM"), year = c(10, 20, 10, 10, 10), month = c(10, 
20, 10, 10, 4), Amount = c(2, 5, 3, 4, 3), Region = c("APAC", 
"EMEA", "APAC", "LATAM", "LATAM")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: @PoojaGangurde Thank you..I updated the answer accordingly. Please check the `dplyr` answer.